# fabric.js - Change brush stroke color after object creation

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

You can get an active object from the canvas and change its properties, e.g. fill, stroke. Is it possible to get a free drawn brush stroke and change its colour?

Here's the function I'm running:

```
function dtUpdateColor(color) {
    let c = color;
    let o = canvas.getActiveObject();

    // If a group selection, do nothing
    if (canvas.getActiveGroup()) {
            canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();
    } else {
        // If single object selected
        if ( c && o ) {
            // Works for shapes, not brush
            canvas.getActiveObject().fill = c;
            // Doesn't work
            canvas.getActiveObject().color = c;
            canvas.renderAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

drawing creates paths which you can change color by changing the `stroke`

Comment: I tried that, didn't work. Tried again there, works. Must have made a mistake in the code the first time. Thanks again. You're becoming the de facto SO fabric.js expert.